# making a new background window in screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I am running screen.  If I enter the command `screen sleep 5`, the current region is replaced by a new screen showing the empty output of sleep.  After 5 seconds, it goes back to the command line.  I want to do something to prevent screen from making the new window current in the region.

I note that if I run `screen sleep 0.01 ; screen sleep 5` that screen switches to the first sleep, then starts the second, and switches back to the original window when the 0.01 seconds expires.  This works, but flashes a blank screen in the region.

I considered using `screen -Q number` to get the current screen number to allow me to select back to it after starting.  This might work, except that screen insists on **displaying** the command result, and completely freezing for 5 seconds while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which seems to be deterministic (the delay technique isn't), but does flash the screen blank.  I write:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -X msgwait 0
number="$(screen -Q number)"
screen "$@"
screen -X select "${number%% *}"
screen -X msgwait 5
```

This also means that msgwait gets reset to its default value (but I've never changed it before).